# Failing unit test of factory with dependency in AngularJS using Jasmine & Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using Jasmine to test an AngularJS factory.

I am having difficulty testing a factory that has a dependency. I have included the code for the factory I am testing and the test code.

The problem is that I am getting errors and the test is failing.

**This is the error I am seeing:**

```
Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.8.5) Testing my Test Service can get an instance of my factory FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/unpr?p0=TestThisServiceProvider%20%3C-%20TestThisService
        at Error (native)
        at /Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:449
        at /Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:32:125
        at Object.c [as get] (/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:30:200)
        at /Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:32:193
        at c (/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:30:200)
        at Object.d [as invoke] (/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:30:417)
        at workFn (/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular-mocks.min.js:6:20731)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular-mocks.min.js:6:20394)
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/.../www/tests/myapp/TestServices/controllers.tests.js:54:43)
        at /Users/.../www/tests/myapp/TestServices/controllers.tests.js:1:1
Firefox 27.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.8) Lighting Control Service can get an instance of my factory FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/unpr?p0=TestThisServiceProvider%20%3C-%20TestThisService
    F/<@/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6
    $b/l.$injector<@/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:32
    c@/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:30
    $b/p.$injector<@/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:32
    c@/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:30
    d@/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular.min.js:30
    workFn@/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular-mocks.min.js:6
    angular.mock.inject@/Users/.../www/lib/angular/angular-mocks.min.js:6
    @/Users/.../www/tests/myapp/TestServices/controllers.tests.js:54
    @/Users/.../www/tests/myapp/TestServices/controllers.tests.js:1
```

**Factory To Test**

```
angular.module('myApp.Module', ["ngResource"])

.factory('TestThisService', function(WebSocketSrvc, $q, $rootScope, $log) {

    return {
        createData: function(type, msg_object, cb_URI, cbfunction) {
            // creates 
        },
        requestData: function(type, cb_URI) {
            // requests
        },
        updateData: function(type, id, msg_object, cb_URI, cbfunction) {
            // updates
        },
        deleteData: function(type, id, cb_URI, cbfunction) {
            // deletes
        }
    }
});
```

**Test Code:**

```
describe("My Service", function() {

  // Load your module.
  beforeEach(module('myApp.Module','myApp.ModuleTwo'));

  // Setup the mock service in an anonymous module.
  beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('WebSocketSrvc', {
        variable: 'value',

        get: function() {

            return 'test';
        },

        send: function(request, cb_URI) {

            return 'result';
        }
            // ... more functions included not displayed.
    });
  }));

  it('can get an instance of my factory', inject(function(TestThisService) {
    expect(TestThisService).toBeDefined();
  }));

});
```

My question is what do I need to do to get my unit test to pass successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you gave you have 2 typos, but I guess this isn't your real code:

- Test Code, line 4:

  ```
  beforeEach(module('MyApp.Module'));
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  beforeEach(module('myApp.Module'));
  ```
- And line 13, you forgot a quote at: `return 'test';`

As the error you get is "TestThisServiceProvider...", I would use `$injector` in a `beforeEach` to inject your service to test. Just after the second `beforeEach(module(function(){...});`

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    myService = $injector.get('TestThisService');
}));
```

I think [`$injector`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector) take care of the dependencies (like `ngResource` in your case).

Comment: I've fixed the typos. You are correct they are not actually in my actual code just an error in the code I entered onto Stack Overflow.

Comment: This does not fix the issue. Perhaps one thing I did not mention is that the dependent piece of code is in a different module. I don't want that dependency to be tested anyways. I would rather test a mock of it's dependency.

Comment: then you must include it in `beforeEach(module(myApp.Module, myApp.otherModule,...));`!

Comment: Awesome it's working now. Must make sure to spell service correctly in `$injector.get('SpellServiceNameCorrectly')`. Thank you for your assistance.